# Invalid redeclaration of type name "uint8" in C

Tags: c

I'm merging 2 C API source codes into an application code.
I have encountered the issue that conflicting in data type in two API source codes .

both have standard generic typedef like the following...

```
typedef signed char int8;
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef signed short sint16;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
...
...
```

Is that any way to wrap around the API source code and don't want to change anything in API source code for solve the error encountered??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt this question can be answered for any language, because it's too broad. Also, you'd do well to remove these typedefs and rewrite the API to use `<stdint.h>` types instead. It'll probably be a simple find and replace operation.

Comment: Redeclaration should not cause any problems. Are you sure both declarations are the same? Or one is using `#define` and the other is using `typedef`?

Comment: Could you show *both* typedef declarations and the actual error you receive?

Comment: Removing typedefs and including stdint.h would jus generate errors, because stdint uses *_t postfixes. You can make a single types header with include guards and include that header to files there was old typedefs you removed.

Comment: @Radon Bad excuse. Like I wrote: it's a simple find and replace operation to fix it.

Comment: Which code do you not want to change? The code doing these typedefs (and using them for implementation)? Or the code including these headers? You only get problems when including the two different typedefs (i.e. their headers) into the same code file.